# Escaping this string? (PHP)

Tags: php, escaping, preg-replace

Hello I am making a PHP Script and I need to escape a string for my preg_replace function and my php server does not display errors for some reason so I am not able to detect where I did the mistake!

The strig is `/*1*\`

I am trying: `'@\/\*1\*\@' => 'HERE!'`

It doesn't work for some reason! Help?

Comment: Use [preg_quote()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to do this for you.... and the last "\" should be "\\"; and the "/" doesn't need escaping as you're not using it as a delimiter

Comment: It would be cooler If I learned how to escape that string.

Comment: @MarkBaker Doesn't work btw..

Comment: for errors messages , edit display_errors line in your the file php.ini of your server to 
display_errors = on
Then restart your web server.

Comment: pl give the full string containg the replacement factor

Comment: Funny how the built-in PHP functions designed for this explicit purpose don't work: `$preg_string = '/*1*\\';
$escaped = preg_quote($preg_string);
echo $escaped;` - generates correctly escaped regexp... just add delimiters and it should be good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `@` as delimiter you don't have to escape the forward slash. However the backslash needs a bit more escaping, once for PHP string context, once for PCRE:

```
 ~/\*1\*\\\\~
```

For clarity `~` used as delimiter here.

(More correctly you would escape *every* backslash as `\\` in PHP strings. Though PHP keeps it if single usually.)

Something I occassionally use to reduce escaping are character classes (which is commonly advised against) and the `x` modifier for readability (which is commonly advised for):

```
~ [/]  [*]  1  [*]  [\\\\]  ~x
```

Note the backslash needs to be multipled still.